# Como desbloquear a porta 80 do Firewall do Windows 8?

Tags: wamp, windows-8

Estou usando WAMP para rodar um servidor local e as vezes quero mostrar os meus projetos para uns amigos, eu já configurei a porta 80 no roteador com o meu IPV4 e tudo mais. Quando faço o testes de porta em algum site diz que a porta tá aberta mas com bloqueio, e quando desativo o Firewall funciona normal, mas não vou deixar o Firewall desativado.

Uso Windows 8

Comment: Painel de Controle -> Ferramentas administrativas -> Firewall; Crie regras de entrada pra porta 80.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Abrir uma porta no Firewall do Windows**

Nesse caso seria necessário abrir uma porta no firewall do windows:

1. Passe o dedo desde a borda direita da tela, toque em Pesquisar (ou,
   se estiver usando um mouse, aponte para o canto superior direito da
   tela, mova o ponteiro do mouse para baixo e clique em Pesquisar),
   digite firewall na caixa de pesquisa e toque ou clique em Firewall
   do Windows.
2. Toque ou clique em **Configurações avançadas**. É possível que você receba uma solicitação
   para fornecer uma senha de administrador ou para confirmar sua
   escolha.
3. Na caixa de diálogo Firewall do Windows com **Segurança Avançada** , no
   painel esquerdo, toque ou clique em **Regras de Entrada** e, no painel
   direito, toque ou clique em **Nova Regra**.
4. Siga as instruções na tela.

A regra nesse caso seria a liberação da **porta 80**, caso você tenha mantido o padrão do apache.

Fonte: http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-BR/windows-8/Windows-Firewall-from-start-to-finish

Comment: Valeu. Eu tava tentando em *Regras de Saída*.